# Removing some characters from a database column

Tags: c#, mysql, character, string-formatting

Is there any way to remove some characters in a database? I have a dates as strings like: "2016-03-09" and I want to remove these dates for last year: (2016-1). Iam using c# and mysql to retrieve and store data.

Comment: I don't understand how you get `2016-1` for your example. Can you please be more specific?

Comment: I have a booking system application people can book a time, stored in database, and want to deleet all for last year which are stored in my db

Comment: Do you want to change the data in the database? Why? Why not just view the data you want? Or do you want to delete entries from the database based on a certain date range?

Comment: Then do so inside the database with a MySql delete command (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html) .

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you want but to replace/remove strings in database usually I use the Replace function
REPLACE(SOURCE, OLDSTRING, NEWSTRING) The New string will be an empty string to remove data.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Deleting records for a specific year can be done by using the `YEAR` function:

```
-- Delete records for a specific year
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE YEAR(date_col) = 2015;
```

Please make sure you have backups before running any deletes on a live database.

Comment: The dates are stored as strings like: "2016-03-09" for example

Comment: You should be storing dates as dates, however `YEAR(a_string)` will work: `SELECT YEAR("2016-03-09");` returns  "2016".

Answer (score 1):

I have a few suggestions;

> I have a dates as strings like..

Why? Why do you store your `DateTime` values as a `string`? You should always use *proper* database types for your variables. Change your column type to [`datetime`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html) and keep your `DateTime` values as such, not their string representations.

Read: [Bad habits to kick : choosing the wrong data type](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/12/bad-habits-to-kick-choosing-the-wrong-data-type)

Then you can execute a delete your command which sending last year as a parameter like;

```
using(var con = new MySqlConnection(conString))
using(var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
    cmd.CommandText = @"delete from yourTableName 
                        where YEAR(yourColumnName) = @year";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@year", MySqlDbType.Int).Value = DateTime.Now.Year - 1;
    con.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear what you mean. But removing records from the database based on a string value can be done with the LIKE command:

```
DELETE FROM my_table WHERE date_col LIKE '2016-__-__'
```

The underscores are wildcards for any character. So all dates from 2016 will be matched.